# What does "exponent 2 nilpotency class 2" mean?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, p-groups

According to the book *The Symmetries of Things*, p. 208, the number of groups of order 2048 "strictly exceeds 1,774,274,116,992,170, which is the exact number of groups of order 2048 that have 'exponent 2 nilpotency class 2.'" I know what exponent 2 means, and I know what nilpotency class 2 means, but I don't know what is meant by "exponent 2 nilpotency class 2" (clearly not the conjunction of the conditions, as exponent 2 implies elementary abelian), and I haven't been able to find out anywhere. So what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ a finite $p$-group. Define $\mathscr{P}_1(G) = G$, and $\mathscr{P}_{i+1}(G) = [\mathscr{P}_i(G), G]\mathscr{P}_i(G)^p$ for $i > 1$. Then there exists an integer $c$ such that $\mathscr{P}_{c+1}(G) = 1$. If $c$ is the smallest such integer, we say that $G$ has exponent-$p$ class $c$.

Note that if $G$ has exponent-$p$ class $c$, then $G$ has nilpotency class at most $c$.

See section 2 in [this article](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/count-pgroups.pdf).